# SSL Failed (SSL: error PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, certbot

I've asked for a certificate cerbot for my domain with the below command on my VPS (Debian) and I got it

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d mydomain.es
```

But, when I run my docker-compose file I get this error:

```
#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain .es/fullchain.pem": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
nginx_mn:
  image: nginx:1.19
  restart: on-failure
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  volumes:
    - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./certbot:/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.es/fullchain.pem
    - ./certbot:/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.es/privkey.pem
    - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  depends_on:
    - web

certbot:
  image: certbot/certbot
  entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h &
     wait $${!}; done;'"
  volumes:
     - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
     - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot

volumes:
  certbot: null
```

and my default.conf

```
upstream server {
    server web:8000;    
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.es;

    #Acme challenge link only needed for verifying domain to this ip address
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;    
       
    listen 443; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    root /apps/back;
    server_name mydomain.es;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.es/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.es/privkey.pem;
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    client_max_body_size 8M;

    location / {        
        proxy_pass http://server;        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;                
    }
}
```

I'm running nginx in my docker. As I run the app on the browser without ssl (port 443) it works. But when I add the below lines, gives and error.

```
    listen 443; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.es/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.es/privkey.pem;
```